# How to build Apache Maven from source without Maven installed? Or how to bootstrap the Maven build?

Tags: java, maven

How do I build Apache Maven 3+ from source without already having Maven installed?

Looking at the Apache site they mention bootstrapping Maven, but I'm having a hard time finding details on this process.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-maven.html

> Note, that you don't need to bootstrap Maven for day to day use, or to develop plugins. While we encourage getting involved and fixing bugs that you find, for day to day use we recommend using the latest release.

I also found this resource which mentions bootstrapping Maven, but it only seems to describe how to clone the various source repositories.

https://github.com/apache/maven-sources/

> Bootstrapping Basics
>
> `mkdir maven`
>
> `cd maven`
>
> `repo init -u https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/maven-sources.git`
>
> `repo sync`
> `repo start master --all`
>
> Then simply use the cloned content with normal git commands.

There must be some way to build Maven without having Maven already installed.

Comment: If you really like to go that way you have to do a time travel. This means first building 3.3.9 via Ant...and afterwards you can build Maven 3.5.X via the build 3.3.9 Maven...the question is why do you like to do that? And what is the advantage of that? BTW: Why are you cloning the whole repositories via repo init...this give much more than you need.

Comment: I have to be able to build Maven without having a circular dependency. I can have Ant as a dependency or an older version of Maven as a dependency. Don't I have to build the Maven plugins and other things like that?

Comment: If you can have an older version of Maven you use Maven 3.3.9 to build Maven 3.5.3...Building plugins is the question if you need / must? There is still the question: Why do you like to do that? What is the problem you have? Do you need to build all the components like plexus parts etc ?

Comment: It's part of our process. I think I should have the ability to choose which components and plugins to build at compile time.

Comment: The question title is a bit confusion. You ask for "how to bootstrap the Maven build" but it seems you actually want to avoid bootstrapping (i.e. you want to avoid building maven with maven)?

Comment: What is the intention of the process to build tools which are already available and only consume an amount of effort which in the end does not really has advantage ?

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, and I had the same question. In my case, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of the Maven binary distribution (which seems silly in retrospect) - that it's Java byte code so there shouldn't be platform issues involved.

Anyway, to answer your question: use the .bin distribution of Maven if you have a need to build from source. You'll still have that original .bin as a dependency, but you can then customize your source build for your intended target system if you so desire.